# PMOS reverse supply

Tags: pmos, reverse-polarity

I'm a little confused, can someone explain to me why this circuit conducts?

I thought that the body diode of the PMOS was in reverse polarity and the source node of PMOS should be at 0V, but simulation shows the opposite.

This is a reverse polarity protection circuit and normally it would be supplied from the source node, but I want to know why in this configuration the circuit behaves like this.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The diode will be in reverse, but the FET is labeled wrong.

You are feeding the 10V to source and pulling the gate low, so FET is on.

Comment: OMG, i'm so blind, thx